# Extra row to SELECT statement, crosstab? Access 2007

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I'm working with some biostats people and of course they love SAS.  I have a select statement below that works for testing the presence of certain problems a person can have.  It's a binary thing so they either do or they don't.  If a person has heart problem and a respiratory problem, then their patientID will be listed twice.  How can I add an extra column of a 1 or 0 for every morbidity?  So, if I have three problems and they are "HEART", "LUNG" and "UTI", an extra column would be generated that has a 1 or 0 based on the presence of that a person had that problem or not.

I suppose I can use Excel to make it a crosstab, but eventually it will need to be in that format.  Below is my SELECT statement.  Thanks, folks!

EDITED:

```
TRANSFORM First(Person.PersonID) AS Morbidity
SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.Age, Person.Sex
FROM tblKentuckyCounties INNER JOIN ((tblComorbidity INNER JOIN comorbidVisits ON tblComorbidity.ID = comorbidVisits.comorbidFK) INNER JOIN (Person INNER JOIN tblComorbidityPerson ON Person.PersonID = tblComorbidityPerson.personID) ON tblComorbidity.ID = tblComorbidityPerson.comorbidityFK) ON tblKentuckyCounties.ID = Person.County
WHERE (((tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="anxiety and depression" Or (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="heart" Or (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="hypertension" Or (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="pressure sores" Or (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="tobacco" Or (tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation)="uti"))
GROUP BY Person.PersonID, Person.Age, Person.Sex, tblComorbidity.comorbidityexplanation
PIVOT Person.Race;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not tested:

```
TRANSFORM IIf([c.comorbidityexplanation]=
      [c.comorbidityexplanation],1,0) AS Morbidity
SELECT p.PersonID, p.Age, p.Sex, p.Race
FROM tblKentuckyCounties kc
INNER JOIN ((tblComorbidity c
INNER JOIN comorbidVisits cv
   ON c.ID = cv.comorbidFK) 
INNER JOIN (Person p
INNER JOIN tblComorbidityPerson cp
   ON p.PersonID = cp.personID) 
   ON c.ID = cp.comorbidityFK) 
   ON kc.ID = p.County
GROUP BY p.PersonID, p.Age, p.Sex, p.Race
PIVOT c.comorbidityexplanation
```

Comment: This result set is too big to be a cross tab, apparently. Hopefully I made it clear that I need a 0 or 1 based on the presence of the criteria 'tobacco, uti, pressure sores. et cetera' for every person. So if they only had a heart problem, they would have a 1 for that, and 0s for the rest.  I think I can problem fiddle it in Excel, but I would much prefer a SQL method.

Comment: @dzilla I have edited to get 1s and 0s. As for the size, perhaps you could create the crosstab from fewer tables and the create a second query based on the crosstab and extra tables to get other required data such as age and sex.

Comment: well, i'm not sure if this would work with a smaller result set or not.  i tried to use the TOP method for only selecting a small subset but it wouldn't let me do that in a crosstab query.

Comment: @dzilla You should be able to limit the set by basing the query on another query of by WHERE. What do you get running on the full set?

Comment: Alright, I got a full data set now, with the correct number of rows ni the cross tab format, but it doesn't look right. I edited what I now have for my SQL statement.

Comment: @dzilla Why are you pivoting race? I thought you wanted a column for each comorbidityexplanation?

Comment: @Remou let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2805/discussion-between-dzilla-and-remou)